# Hibernate 5.4.x Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.MappingException: Error accessing stax stream : origin(null)

Tags: java, hibernate

I use hibernate 5.4.1. Everything worknormally util Jun 28 2019 can not start service.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document: null (INPUT_STREAM)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.InputStreamXmlSource.doBind(InputStreamXmlSource.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.InputStreamXmlSource.doBind(InputStreamXmlSource.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.bind(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.addInputStream(MetadataSources.java:382)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:475)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.MappingException: Error accessing stax stream : origin(null)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.seekRootElementStartEvent(AbstractBinder.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.doBind(AbstractBinder.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.InputStreamXmlSource.doBind(InputStreamXmlSource.java:43)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,2]
Message: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:601)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:276)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.EventReaderDelegate.peek(EventReaderDelegate.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.BufferedXMLEventReader.peek(BufferedXMLEventReader.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.seekRootElementStartEvent(AbstractBinder.java:137)
    ... 78 more
```

Comment: Whatever XML you are trying to parse and/or the related DTD is not well formed.  `The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.`

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found root cause. Hibernate update [dtd file](http://hibernate.org/dtd) on Jun 27 2019. Seem updated file hibernate-mapping.dtd not comparative will previous version.

Before my hibernate entity mapping *.hbm.xml use:

> "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping.dtd">

After fix, change to bellow, and it work:

> "https://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

Answer (score 0):

A very similar problem popped up with a hibernate-based service I maintain yesterday. The service had been running smoothly since 2017 (and had not been modified since then) but suddenly started failing on 2019-06-28 with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 26; Element type "hibernate-configuration" must be declared.
```

The DOCTYPE block in my hibernate config file looked like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd//hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

For reasons I don't fully understand, removing the extra slash character in the DTD URL fixed the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

I'm guessing both of our problems were caused by some unusual change to how hibernate.org is serving up those DTD files.